# Python Image crop in selected boundaries

Tags: python, image, crop

I need help in python cropping for selected boundaries within a color.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/05MzC.png)

[Color i use](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrPLx.png)

Thank you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.